# AsyncTask not locking main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, preferences, android-asynctask, listpreference

I'm using following code to fill a custom ListPreference dialog. Since the fill procedure takes a lot of time i want to show a progress dialog during the fill procedure.

My problem is that filler.execute() does not block onPrepareDialogBuilder and functions goes till the end before values are filled causing an exception... Any idea?

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {        
    // Load data
    if (this.getEntries()==null) {
        FillerTask filler = new FillerTask();
        filler.execute();
    }   
    Log.d(TAG, "Filler finished");
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
}
```

Here is Filltertask code, basically he looks for every activity with a MAIN Intent filling a list:

```
private class FillerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[][]> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Dismiss dialog");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyListPreference.this.getContext(), "", "Doing stuff...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[][] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return fill();
    }

    public String[][] fill() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fill started");

        CREATE LISTS...

        // Done
        Log.d(TAG, "Fill done");
        String[][] result = new String[][] {entryNames, entryValues};
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[][] result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Post execute");
        MyListPreference.this.setEntries(result[0]);
        MyListPreference.this.setEntryValues(result[1]);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, best way to do this is override the onClick method and let the AsyncTask postExecute call the "super()", so click is not passed until content is loaded and during load progress bar is correctly displayed.

Comment: John, could you please post your final code? How do you access super for the ListPreference from the AsyncTask? Thank you very much!

Comment: update: it should be MyListPreference.super.onClick(); 
The tricky thing is, that eclipse doesn't include super in the completion for "MyListPreference.". But there's again full completion after typing "MyListPreference.super." :-)

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that filler.execute() does not block onPrepareDialogBuilder and functions goes till the end before values are filled causing an exception... Any idea?

That is the entire point behind an `AsyncTask`. The "Async" in `AsyncTask` means asynchronous.

Use your `AsyncTask` to get your data. Then, in `onPostExecute()`, display the dialog.

Comment: How can i display the dialog if i am inside the ListPreference itself?? I need to block "onPrepareDialogBuilder" somewhere, probably i should not use ListPreference at all and use an activity with a list

Comment: @JohnUopini: Yes, I would not recommend a ListPreference for this case. There is no point in you bothering with an AsyncTask if you need to block the UI thread anyway. Another approach is to get the data before displaying the PreferenceActivity. Or, start the AsyncTask when you display the PreferenceActivity, but have the ListPreference disabled until onPostExecute().

Comment: Your last option is nice, i can start the Async during "createView" and then use get and lock only when dialog is showed, this makes things faster.

Answer (score 0):

`asyntask` doesn't lock main thread, it just drops a message to message queue of main thread